# Can I use a Lid for a glass vessel for cooking in microwave?

Tags: equipment

Can you use a lid for a glass vessel when cooking in microwave?

Comment: Glass is fine in the microwave and lidded containers are fine- as long as steam can escape without an explosion.

Comment: ... and of course, as long as the lid itself is microwave safe. E.g., not a metal lid.

Answer (score 1):

What is your lid made of? What are you cooking? Some lids won't be safe, some dishes can't be sealed airtight or they will explode. If the lid is glass or some other safe material and you aren't creating a lot of steam pressure or the like, you'll be fine.